# Finding a childs row and column in UniformGrid based on Index in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In WPF, I have a Uniform Grid and would like to be able to find the row and column based on the index of a child element.

I know there is a mathematical way of doing this and would rather not use a normal Grid.

If it helps, I can get the total number of rows and columns by using:

```
Math.Sqrt([*uniformgrid*].Children.Count)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry this is in C# but in principle you need to do

```
int rows = theGrid.Rows;
int columns = theGrid.Columns;

int index = theGrid.Children.IndexOf(childElement);

int row = index/columns;  // divide
int column = index%columns;  // modulus
```

And in VB.NET

```
dim rows as Integer = theGrid.Rows
dim columns as Integer = theGrid.Columns
dim index as Integer = theGrid.Children.IndexOf(childElement)

dim row as integer = index \ columns
dim column as integer = index mod columns
```

Comment: It doesnt seem like mod is working for the column. I tried 4 Mod 12 which should and its returning 4.

Comment: 4 mod 12 is 4.  12 mod 4 = 0, 13 mod 4 = 1 etc.