# Data Binding between a double array and a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am rather new to C#/XAML and have difficulties to do Data Binding. I would like to do Data binding between an c# double array and a XAML grid.

```
// This double array is filled with Square objects which are elements of the map
Square[,] worldMapGrid = new Square[4,4];

// For showing an very simple example, we can fill it like this:
worldMapGrid[0,0] = new SquareMountain();
worldMapGrid[0,1] = new SquareDesert();
worldMapGrid[0,1] = new SquarePrairie();
...
```

I have in my XAML code this :

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="MapGrid" Width="600" Height="600" Columns="4" Rows="4">
    FILL WITH SQUARES HERE
</UniformGrid>
```

And in my ResourceDictionnary :

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonSquare" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">   
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="path1" Fill="CHANGE HERE"/>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to fill the `UniformGrid` named MapGrid with `ButtonSquare` objects, and set their Rectangle color `Fill` property according to the type of object in the `worldMapGrid`. Actually, `MapGrid` is a visual representation of `worldMapGrid`.

So I want to do Data Binding between these 2 objects, but I am struggling with this concept. Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a sample window xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="SquareUniformGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SquareUniformGrid"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="700">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:SquareConverter x:Key="squareConverter"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="mountain">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonSquare}"
                Background="Black"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="desert">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonSquare}"
                Background="Brown"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="prairie">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonSquare}"
                Background="Green"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ButtonTemplateSelector x:Key="selector" Mountain="{StaticResource mountain}" Desert="{StaticResource desert}" Prairie="{StaticResource prairie}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Background="Gray" Margin="8" Width="600" Height="600" ItemsSource="{Binding MapGrid}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="4" Columns="4"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Here is the corresponding viewmodel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Member Variables
    private List<Square> worldMapGrid = new List<Square>();
    #endregion

    #region Ctr
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        BuildWorldMap();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void BuildWorldMap()
    {
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareDesert());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareDesert());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareDesert());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareDesert());

        MapGrid.Add(new SquareMountain());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareMountain());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareMountain());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquareMountain());

        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());

        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
        MapGrid.Add(new SquarePrairie());
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string _propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public List<Square> MapGrid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.worldMapGrid;
        }
        set
        {
            this.worldMapGrid = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MapGrid");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the code for the DataTemplateSelector:

```
    public class ButtonTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    #region Member Variables

    #endregion

    #region Ctr
    public ButtonTemplateSelector()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Overrides
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is SquareDesert)
        {
            return Desert;
        }
        if (item is SquareMountain)
        {
            return Mountain;
        }
        if (item is SquarePrairie)
        {
            return Prairie;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public DataTemplate Mountain
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate Desert
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate Prairie
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This set of code effectively draws a uniform grid with colored tiles based on the worldmapgrid settings.

Oops, forgot the style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonSquare" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ok..then perhaps I'm not understanding your issue.  As I read it, you're looking for a way to bind ButtonSquare objects to your UniformGrid with the rectangle fill of the ButtonSquare bound to the type of Square object in your WorldMapGrid.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, actually I would like to do 2 bindings :
1) The `UniformGrid` must be populated according the double array `worldMapGrid`, a modification in `worldMapGrid` modifies automatically the `UniformGrid`
2) A `Button` in the `UniformGrid` corresponds to a `Square`, and the color of the button must be green if the `Square is a `SquarePrairie`, and so on.

Comment: Ok let me whip something up - will be back in a few

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that you cannot bind to a double array.  So you'll need to work something out to convert your double array to a single array, but I have something that works now.  Updating my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will work on this with the ideas you gave me. I am creating a `MyButton : Button` so that I can add a property to bind the color. EDIT : I've just seen you added some code, I'll try it and come back later to valid your answer if it works. :)

Comment: It says that `SquareConverter` cannot be found. Do I need to create a class ?

Comment: Sorry, was trying something else - just remove that line in the Window.Resources section.

Comment: One more question : There is an issue with `[CallerMemberName]`. Visual Studio says that it cannot find it, even if I used `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices`, because I work with .NET 4.0. Is there a way to do the same with 4.0 ?

Comment: Editing my original view model for .NET 4.0

Comment: It works great ! I would like to get the row and the column when I click on a button in the UniformGrid, and I cant get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092688/finding-a-childs-row-and-column-in-uniformgrid-based-on-index-in-wpf) to work. Do you have any idea ?