# System.InvalidOperationException when trying yo access UniformGrid.Children in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am populating an `UniformGrid`with binding. The source is a `Square[,]`, and the `UniformGrid`is filled with `Button` objects.

Here is what I did :
[Data Binding between a double array and a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148686/data-binding-between-a-double-array-and-a-grid)

I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` when trying to do this :

```
private void OnClickButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    UniformGrid grid = ItemControlGrid.ItemsPanel.LoadContent() as UniformGrid;
    int rows = grille.Rows;
    int columns = grille.Columns;
    UIElementCollection children = grid.Children; // I get the Exception here
    int index = children.IndexOf(b);
    int row = index / columns;
    int column = index % rows;
}
```

Here is my XAML :

```
<ItemsControl Background="Gray" Margin="0" Width="800" Height="800"  
    x:Name="ItemControlGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MapGrid}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid 
                IsItemsHost="true"
                x:Name="My_UniformGrid" Rows="25" Columns="25"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Why do I get this `Exception`?

Comment: We need more, get tine Childre shouldn't throw an exception. Is there something in the Exception message?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line where you get an exception to:

```
ItemCollection children = ItemControlGrid.Items;
```

The rest of the code should compile just as fine. I assume that `grille` is actually `grid`.

```
<ItemsControl Background="Gray" Margin="0" Width="800" Height="800"  
    x:Name="ItemControlGrid">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="true" Rows="25" Columns="25"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- First two elements are just dummies to test the result-->
    <Control />
    <Image />
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" />
</ItemsControl>
```

Codebehind:

```
void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = (Button) sender;
    var grid = ItemControlGrid.ItemsPanel.LoadContent() as UniformGrid;
    var rows = grid.Rows;
    var columns = grid.Columns;
    var children = ItemControlGrid.Items;
    var index = children.IndexOf(b);
    var row = index/columns;
    var column = index%rows;
    //column will be 2
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but when I do `Console.WriteLine(row+","+column));` I always get : `0,-1`

Comment: @Pigrou I've added an example to my post. Try it and the modify it accordingly to your requirements. Let me know through a comment if it works.

Comment: I get `false`with `children.Contains(b);`

Comment: @Pigrou I'm afraid I can't help any further, since the code I've pasted works for me.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the binding. The sender does not even have a Parent. Thanks anyways.