# How to "get" the row and column of a component in a UniformGrid?

Tags: .net, wpf, uniformgrid

I see from the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the UniformGrid class does not support an attached property for "setting" columns or rows. In my current programming problem I have the situation that I have added components to the UniformGrid but in the click handlers of the components I've added to the UniformGrid I want the components to be aware of which row and column they wound up in.

Even if it is impossible to "set" this data, is there a way to "get" it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a childs row and column in UniformGrid based on Index in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092688/finding-a-childs-row-and-column-in-uniformgrid-based-on-index-in-wpf)

Comment: @dkozl thanks for the link, the solution to taking IndexOf and using multiplication operations with the UniformGrid's Columns and Rows properties was not something I found when researching the question, but it does solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in solution to do this in O(1) time, only in O(n) time by getting the element's index in the UniformGrid's children collection by searching for it, and then applying division and modulo operators in combination with the UniformGrid's `Columns` property. This is shown in the SO article [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092688/finding-a-childs-row-and-column-in-uniformgrid-based-on-index-in-wpf?lq=1)

If you are looking for a faster means of doing this you will have to keep track of this yourself, perhaps by introducing the values as properties in your component at the moment you add them to your UniformGrid.